# "Desktop file does not exist" error when using qmake based template in Ubuntu SDK

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, sdk

Just as the LaunchPad bug says: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtcreator-plugin-ubuntu/+bug/1512094

Using the Ubuntu SDK template "QML App with C++ plugin (qmake)" or any other qmake template, the app it creates fails to run on the connected device.
When the app is run it does not start and a "Desktop file does not exist" dialog pops up.

Answer (score 1):

The click chroot is outdated or broken.

Select the "Tools..." menu item under the Options menu. Go to the Ubuntu tab in the Options dialog and delete the chroots. After that recreate the new chroots.